# Proof regarding limits of functions and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> For a function f$:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ define what is meant by $ \ f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ x \rightarrow -\infty$ and prove that it holds if and only if whenever $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $x_n \rightarrow -\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ it follows that $f(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Now this seems like quite a long question, but here is my attempt so far;
$\bullet$Firstly to state the definition of "$ \ f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ x \rightarrow -\infty$" $$ \forall \ \ M \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \exists \ \ N \in \mathbb{R} \ \ s.t \ \ f(x)>M  \ \ for \ \ all \ \ x<N$$
$\bullet$ To show the "$ \implies$" we must show; "$ \ f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ x \rightarrow -\infty$" implies  "whenever $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $x_n \rightarrow -\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ it follows that $f(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$  "
Intuitively this is quite obvious as any sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ which tends to $-\infty$ , then $f(x_n)$ must tend to infinity by the first statement. but how do I rigorously show this??

Any help or tips on this part of the proof or the left implication part would be much appreciated.

Comment: First of all thanks for showing up your work. To show that $f(x_{n}) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ we take any number $M$. Then there is an $N$ such that $f(x) > M$ for $x < N$. Now $x_{n} \to -\infty$ hence there is a positive integer $m$ such that $x_{n} < N$ for $n \geq m$. It follows that $f(x_{n}) > M$ for $n \geq m$. And then we are done.